# $scope value unpredictable in $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to indefinitely loop through a JSON array (named playbook below).

I have the following code:

```
$scope.loadPlaybook = function () {
    $http.get('/static/lib/playbook.json')
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.data.playbook = res.data;

            console.log('Playbook data:', $scope.data.playbook);

            $interval(function () {
                console.log('Trying to access from $interval:', $scope.data.playbook);
            }, 1000);
        },
        function (err) {
            // ..
        });
};
```

Sometimes, `$scope.data.playbook` is defined in the `$interval` callback, most of the times not.

70% of the times of when I load the page, the output looks like this:

[image]

30% of the times of when I load the page, the output looks like this:

[image]

I'm using Angular 1.5.1 and Google Chrome.

Comment: try log $scope.data and expand and then expand the data and see you have all your data.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question directly but as far as I know, be aware that `console.log()` shows a preview of the object passed as parameter at the time it is running and then it updates with the current object state when you click on the displayed preview in the console. If you want to see the state of an object at a certain time you can `console.log(angular.copy(sourceObj))`. You can combine those two to check if $scope.data was overwritten by somewhere else after it was initially set.

Hope it helps!